# Appium 1.4.13 How to resolve error: Could not detect Mac OS X Version from sw_vers output: '10.12 ']?

Tags: appium, ios, mobile-automation

Environment : macOS Sierra, Appium version 1.4.13 (Draco)

I am not able run appium. Please help, How to fixed this issue?

```
appium doctor has not worked. 
Error :
info AppiumDoctor ### Diagnostic starting ###
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ Xcode is installed at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
[Error: Could not detect Mac OS X Version from sw_vers output: '10.12
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an [issue](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/7031) with that build of Appium. Towards the bottom of the issue page there is a linked solution on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40129794/how-to-fix-error-could-not-detect-mac-os-x-version-from-sw-vers-output-10-12/40168992#40168992). I have made the switch to the desktop app version of Appium and it works well (and requires less setup). Either way, the issue is said to be fixed in more recent versions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am using version 1.4.13 not 1.5.3 and which xcode version working well for you? In my case I am using 8.3

Comment: Don't get hung up on old version numbers without trying a newer version. I am currently using Appium 1.6.4 and XCode 8.3.

Comment: yes, agree. I have installed 1.6.5 but how to start execution programatically. It was working well before but now I am searching for solution.